# Can you make a http request and forge the Referer value to be some arbitrary website?

Tags: http, http-referer

I'm new to HTTP protocol and I have limited experience in networking.
I'm wondering which http request headers can be set arbitrarily and which headers cannot.

For example, can I create a http request to `www.twitter.com` and set the `Referer` header value to `www.google.com` even though I did not visit the `www.twitter.com` website by clicking a link on `www.google.com`??

Can it be forged?
If so, which other http request headers can be forged like this?

Comment: **All of them**. The important matter is how the host can verify them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you. Could you please give a few examples of how the host verifies a potentially forged HTTP request header?